# Obscure Relational Database Mapping to C# Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net

apologies for the previous post, sometime writing the questions actually solves it too ;) as in "the answer is in the question"

So I'm trying to interface an old primitive database system that is accessed vi a DLL entry point, however some work has been done on object rational mapping where one can create objects of each table and access the database that way, however for viewing the entire database it's seams impossible it parse so many tables (1000's or so objects) 
However if I can create some sort of schema mapping to a C# Dataset class then that would make it accessible.

Hope that give some info into what i'm trying to attempt

Comment: Describe your environment (kind of DBMS) and improve your spelling. Would help a lot to get some answers.

Comment: ...and perhaps some examples of classes and tables. I'm lost as to what you are after.

Comment: Is it at all possible that someone else may have worked with the same database system? If so, you should at least provide the name of the system - someone else might have already solved the same problems.

Comment: Still needs more clarity/detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of DBMS you're trying to access, but if your legacy system has some kind of query language, you could write some kind of interface to query the database (SQL to legacy language class, a SQL driver whatever).

I'm not sure why you would do a object-relational mapping to this. Why not write an interface that would let you query it in a simple, yet effective manner?

edit: I see you write "Object rational mapping", I suppose you mean object relational mapping